# Assign values to knn search elements

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, vector, knn

I need to search the nearest 3 neighbors to my sample data.  My code is the following:

```
Sample = vec_1;      

Training = [vec_2;vec_3;vec_4;vec_5;vec_6];

IDX = knnsearch(Training,Sample,'K',3);

disp('Results: ');
disp (IDX);
```

I got:

```
Results: 
     5     3     2
```

My question is this: I want to assign image to each value:

```
for example for 5, img1.jpg
            for 3, img2.jpg........ so on
```

Comment: @rayryeng.... basically the question is i want to assign stored images to these vectors

Comment: for IDX=1,imshow(img1)....    forIDX=2,imshow(img2)... and so on   BUT this i Found is not a suitable way to assign images to vector elemnts ...

Comment: %%%%Assign images to knn search elements%%%%%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct a cell array of images where you can access the image by the particular index from KNN.  You don't need to use the actual vector itself.  The index can be used as the key instead.

Do something like the following:

```
 maxIndex = max(IDX);
 imgCellArray = cell(1, maxIndex);
 imgCellArray{IDX(1)} = img1;
 imgCellArray{IDX(2)} = img2;
 imgCellArray(IDX(3)} = img3;
```

Therefore, if `IDX = [5 3 2]`, then the above code will allow you to access images in the way you wanted.   `imgCellArray{5}` will give you `img1`, and is located at index 5, `imgCellArray{3}` will give you `img2` and is located at index 3 and so on.

Bear in mind that there will be some empty slots in your cell array that haven't been populated.  In particular, at locations 1 and 4.  However, with regards to memory you shouldn't be too concerned as very little memory is allocated (if at all... I'm not quite sure here) to represent the empty cell.

Comment: Thanks bro! That means a lot to me... Now I got o/p something like this ...... imgCellArray = [] [] [] [] [201x151 uint8] imgCellArray = [] [] [201x151 uint8] [] [201x151 uint8] imgCellArray = [] [201x151 uint8] [201x151 uint8] [] [201x151 uint8]

Comment: So now if I have large data set of i.e 1000 Training images for example in my first question i used 5 images and with the help of knn search i got best 3 images.. so with this above code it would be a very length approach,, i am very beginner at loop and control statements.So plz help me again,i shall be very thankful to you.

Comment: How are you loading in your images?  Can you show me the rest of your code?

Comment: Thanks! Big Brother for your continuous support... I will post my code separately

Comment: My actual code is some what like this & as this is for five training values,,,,

%SAmple DAta

vec_1=[2.35 2.48 1.25 2.42 -8.51];   

%#Training Values

vec_2=[2.48 2.99 1.32 2.88 -10.03];

vec_3=[2.93 2.93 1.33 2.87 -10.06];

vec_4=[2.92 3.04 1.08 2.92 -9.99];

vec_5=[2.99 3.12 1.64 3.09 -10.85];

vec_6=[2.31    2.59    1.01    2.49   -8.42];

Sample = vec_1;      

Training = [vec_2;vec_3;vec_4;vec_5;vec_6];

IDX = knnsearch(Training,Sample,'K',3);

disp('Results: ');
disp (IDX);

Comment: %as per your code....
maxIndex = max(IDX);
 imgCellArray = cell(1, maxIndex);
 imgCellArray{IDX(1)} = img1;
 imgCellArray{IDX(2)} = img2;
 imgCellArray{IDX(3)} = img3;
 
now the question is same if i have large no of "training values" for ex. vec_7,vec_8.........vec_1000. No doubt with knnsearch i will get best of 3 from 1000 training values but this would make program more bulky ... so i request u to suggest me some proper technique to handle this stuff..

Comment: these images i am loading from matlab default directory i.e C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin